# Window.resize or document.resize which works & which doesn't? VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using `Vuetable` and its awesome.

I am trying to create a top horizontal scroll, which I have done and its working fine. But I need to assign some events on the `window.resize`.

I created a component such as

```
<template>
<div class="top-scrollbar">
  <div class="top-horizontal-scroll"></div>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.top-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-left: 14px;

  .top-horizontal-scroll {
    height: 20px;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    document.querySelector("div.top-scrollbar").addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    document.querySelector("div.vuetable-body-wrapper").addEventListener('scroll', this.tableScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      document.querySelector("div.vuetable-body-wrapper").scrollLeft = document.querySelector("div.top-scrollbar").scrollLeft
    },

    tableScroll() {
      document.querySelector("div.top-scrollbar").scrollLeft = document.querySelector("div.vuetable-body-wrapper").scrollLeft
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am calling it above the table such as `<v-horizontal-scroll />`

I created a mixin as

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    setScrollBar: () => {
      let tableWidth = document.querySelector("table.vuetable").offsetWidth;
      let tableWrapper = document.querySelector("div.vuetable-body-wrapper").offsetWidth;

      document.querySelector("div.top-horizontal-scroll").style.width = tableWidth + "px";
      document.querySelector("div.top-scrollbar").style.width = tableWrapper + "px"
    }
  }
})
```

And I am calling it when the user component on which `Vuetable` is being created

```
  beforeUpdate() {
    document.addEventListener("resize", this.setScrollBar());
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.setScrollBar);
      this.setScrollBar()
    });
  },
```

I want to understand how this resizing event working.

If I change even a single thing in the above code. I am starting to have issues.

Either it doesn't set the width of scroll main div correctly or even `this.setScrollBar` don't work on resizing.

I am not clear what is the logic behind this and how it is working?